# Simplifying wave algebra & the meaning of $u$ being less than $v$

Tags: special-relativity, waves

In my physics class today, we were looking at the expression $(1-(u/v))^{-1}$. In a single step, the professor showed that this expression equals $1+u/v$.
How is that? Is it the binomial theorem?

If $u$ is much less than $v$, as needed to write out the expression with a Taylor series approximation, how can that be? I thought that $v$ was the speed through a material, so shouldn’t it be lower than $u$? And on that note, if you don’t mind, what exactly is $u$?

Comment: Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside, like this `$v^2=\frac{GM}{r}$` . See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yes, it's the first order approximation for small values of $u \over v$. You can get it using binomial theorem or using Taylor expansion about zero of $1 \over {1 - x}$.

Comment: @FGSUZ Thanks for the link to laTex instructions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming  your professor had assumed $\frac{u}{v}<1$, let us write $x=\frac{u}{v}$ and let us denote $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Now if you know how Taylor expansion works then you can find it easily and approximate f(x) up to linear order in $x$.
Let me also clarify you that $f(x)\approx 1+x$ not both are equal and generally for practical purpose linear approximation is enough and higher order terms/corrections on $x$ gives more and more accuracy to $f(x)$.
From high school we already know infinite geometric series,So we can write for $x<1$
$$1+x+x^2+\dots +x^n+\dots=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ where $x$ is common ratio of the infinite geometric series.
$$\implies f(x)=1+x+o(x^2)$$ Thus $f(x)\approx 1+x$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mr. Fields! As I commented on the other answerer’s post, if u is much less than v, how can that be? I thought that v was the speed through a material, so shouldn’t it be lower than u? Many thanks!

Comment: @Yelena You keep asking about $u$. You haven't stated the meaning of $u$ anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is the first order Taylor expansion and is valid for $\frac{u}{v} \ll1$.

Comment: Thank you so very much to both of you! If it u is much less than v, how can that be? I thought that v was the speed through a material, so a material slows it down from its potential speed? Many thanks!

Comment: It's a mathematical statement, not a physics statement.  The application to physics requires the student (or professor) to assign meaning to the symbols.

Comment: Thank you! I asked about this today and learned that “u” means the transmitter’s speed. As it moves along it sends out a wave with speed “v”.

Comment: @Yelena So it makes sense indeed that $u\ll v$.

Comment: @Oбжорoв Yes, thanks!